# Кодировка phpMyAdmin для PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, utf-8

Помогите пожалуйста, я понять не могу почему у меня показывает Русский текст -> ???????????
Я кодировку поменял utf8mb4 потому что показывало так, поменял на utf8_general_ci и даже в такой кодировке показывает ????????
Вот скриншоты:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmAJG.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте указывать кодировку при подключении к БД в коде бэкэнда

Comment: указал, даже попробовал отправить сам запрос на изменение кодировки через phpMyAdmin, ничего не помогает, не знаю уже что делать